# Predictively computing potentially needed values on large shared data structure with infrequent updates

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a system I need to design with low latency in mind, processing power and memory are generous. I have a large (several GB) data structure that is updated once every few seconds. Many (read only) operations are going to run against this data structure between updates, in parallel, accessing it heavily. As soon as an update occurs, all computations in progress should be cleanly cancelled, as their results are invalidated by the update.

The issue I'm running into here is that writes are infrequent enough, and readers access so often that locking around individual reader access would have a huge hit to performance. I'm fine with the readers reading invalid data, but then I need to deal with any invariants broken (assertions) or segfaults due to stale pointers, etc. At the same time, I can't have readers block writers, so reader-writer locks acquired at every reader's thread start is unacceptable.

The only solution I can think of has a number of issues, which is to allocate a mapping with mmap, put the readers in separate processes, and mprotect the memory to kill the workers when it's time to update. I'd prefer a cross-platform solution (ideally pure C++), however, and ideally without forking every few seconds. This would also require some surgery to get all the data structures located in shm.

Something like a revocable lock would do exactly what I need, but I don't know of any libraries that provide such functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was a database I'd use multi-versions concurrency control. Readers obtain a logical snapshot while the underlying physical data structures are mostly lock-free (or locked very shortly and fine-grainedly).

You say your memory is generously equipped. Can you just create a complete copy of the data structure? Then you modify the copy and swap it out atomically.

Or, can you use immutable data-structures so that readers continue to use the old version and the writer creates new objects?

Or, you implement MVCC in a fine-grained way. Let's say you want to version a hash-set. Instead of keeping one value per key, you keep one value per key per version. Readers read from the latest version that is <= the version that existed when they started to read. Writers create a new version number for each write "transaction". Only when all writes are complete readers would start picking up changes from the new version. This is how MVCC-databases do it.

Besides these approaches I also liked your mmap idea. I don't think you need a separate process is your OS supports copy-on-write memory mappings. Then you can map the same memory area multiple times and provide a stable snapshot to readers.

Comment: I hadn't heard of MVCC, that's a really useful idea on examination. I have a number of complex data structures this would work for, but at the heart of this is a giant byte array, so I'd have to version every byte, greatly increasing the size in RAM (or the complexity if I chunk it). One thing that may save me is most of the updates are very small delta (change one value or two), though the giant array can change in a large area. Thanks for the thoughts!

Comment: @Alex ok sounds like you can version it using mmap. Or, you maybe there is some way to chunk the data so that you can update few chunks and keep most the same. That reduces versioning costs. You can't have pointers inside of the structures with this approach, though, because memory locations can change. You probably need to store an offset to a base pointer.